# PyGreSQL - Unable to Insert Data

Tags: postgresql, pygresql

I am using CentOS-6 with Python 3.8, PostgreSQL 12 and PyGreSQL 5.2.2.  This is the error I get trying to insert data into my database.

```
>>> db.insert('settings', None, **data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pg.py", line 2322, in insert
    adapt = params.add
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pg.py", line 1667, in __getattr__
    if self.db:
AttributeError: 'pg.Connection' object has no attribute 'escape_identifier'
```

Can anyone point me towards what is wrong?

Comment: Try without the `None`.

Comment: Using this insert statement without a None as you suggested: 
   `db.insert('settings', **data)` 
returns the same error as shown in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `escape_identifier` on the connection corresponds to the function `PQescapeIdentifier` in libpq. It exists since PostgreSQL 9 which is required by PyGreSQL 5.2. PyGreSQL does not compile support for these functions if it is installed with the `no-escaping-funcs` option or if it thinks PostgreSQL is older than version 9.

Since you say that you have PostgreSQL 12 installed, a possible explanation could be that you still have the client library (`libpq`) of an old PostgreSQL version installed as well, and the `pg_config` tool reports that old version. You should check this with `pg_config --version`. The `pg_config` tool is in `libpq-devel`, so make sure you have `libpq` and `libpq-devel` installed for PostgreSQL 12.

You can also try to explicitly enable the escaping functions by installing PyGreSQL with `python setup.py build_ext --escaping-funcs install`, but you will still need the latest `libpq`, and there will be other functions disabled as well when PyGreSQL thinks that libpq is too old. So the proper solution is to make sure `libpq` is up to date and `pg_config --version` reports the corresponding PostgreSQL version.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I do have an older PostgreSQL installed.  It is version 8.4.   

I've made sure my links are correct:
    `/usr/lib/libpq.so --> /usr/pgsql-12/lib/libpq.so.5.12
    /usr/lib/libpq.so.5 --> /usr/pgsql-12/lib/libpq.so.5.12`   

I also deleted /usr/bin/pg_config and made a link instead:
`/usr/bin/pg_config --> /usr/pgsql-12/bin/pg_config`
Running `pg_config --version' now returns PostgreSQL 12.5, so that is correct.  

I didn't compile PyGreSQL by hand.  I installed via pip.  

I still get the same error inserting data into the DB.  Any other ideas for me?

Comment: It is important that you install PyGreSQL *after* making these changes. If it's already installed, remove it (pip uninstall) and install it again, so that it is compiled against the newer pqlib during installation.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Re-installing pip did the trick!  Everything is working now.